# CSS3 :target selector with Angular.js

Tags: css, angularjs, target, firefox-os, drawer

I'm trying to implement CSS3 selectors using :target for a drawer animation, without luck.
Using $locationProvider.html5Mode(false); the animations is not working. Turning that feature to "true" is allowing me :target selector but the routing is not working and displaying anything.

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers',
  'myApp.services'
]).
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
  $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
}]);


...
<ul>
   <li><a href="#view1">item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#view2">item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Anyone has a suggestion or idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use a reference app to get started, and `ng-animate` to integrate the animation:

```html
    <html ng-app="demo">
      <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgithub.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css">
    
        <style>
          a {
            font-size: 300%;
          }
          #Squidward:target { color: red }
        </style>
        
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          angular.module('demo', [
          ]).controller('MainCtrl', function(
            $scope
          ){
            $scope.items = [{
              name: 'Squidward'
            }, {
              name: 'Plankton'
            }];
            
            $scope.add = function() {
              $scope.items.push({
                name: 'Patrick'
              });
            };
          });
        </script>
      </head>
      
      <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div>
          <a href="#Squidward" ng-click="add()">Add More Patrick</a>
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-animate="{
              enter: 'animated flip'
            }">
              <a id={{item.name}}>{{item.name}}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </body>
    
    </html>
```

**References**

- [AngularJS Wiki: JSFiddle Examples](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/JSFiddle-Examples)
- [AngularJS ng-animate + target Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DImwTz3wAiZllhgTrlNR?p=preview)
- [Getting started with AngularJS](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-angularjs.html)
- [Angular JS 1.2x Developer Guide:Internet Explorer Compatibility](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/guide/ie)
- [Firefox OS Simulator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firefox-os-simulator/)
- [Todo App for Firefox OS](https://github.com/iFadey/fos-todo-app)